# Fading Image View image (alpha 0.5), how to make it show up and turn back to default

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I am building this dice app game, and I would like to make the dice color fade everytime I press the roll button, and the roll button as well, and as soon the Image view changes, fade them to default.

I can only make it fade but I can't figure out how to turn it to default immediatily.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var diceImageView1: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var diceImageView2: UIImageView!

    @IBAction func rollButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        
        let diceArray = [#imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceOne"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceTwo"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceThree"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceFour"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceFive"), #imageLiteral(resourceName: "DiceSix")]
    
        
        diceImageView1.image = diceArray [Int.random(in: 0...5)]
        diceImageView2.image = diceArray [Int.random(in: 0...5)]

        diceImageView1.alpha = 0.5
        diceImageView2.alpha = 0.5
        
        sender.alpha = 0.5
```

Comment: I don´t think you want to set it to `default immediatily`. You wouldn´t see any effect, would you?

Comment: Draw out a timeline of what you want to happen. It sounds when the user taps the button you want:

your dice to fade to 0.5 alpha over some short time interval. (let's say 0.2 seconds)

Then, once it's faded, you want to swap to different dice images and immediately have your dice and button snap back to full opacity. Is that right?

Comment: Once you have a timeline for what you want, you need to map out a sequence of UIView animations that gives you the effect you are after. I suggest you search for tutorials on UIView animation.